# SQLBulkCopy & InMemory tables

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

helping out on a project where the data loading is done using C# & SQLBulkCopy to normal rowstore tables - does anyone know if there are any issues or gotchas with continuing with SQLBulkCopy but swapping the target table to be an InMemory table ? Is this even possible ?

Have tried searching but going around in circles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use an **In-Memory Table** with the SQLBulkCopy class. I'm not aware of any additional gotchas but did come across this [Git Issue](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Extensions/issues/85) in terms of ensuring you properly configure the options of it (depending on the size of your table).

You guys should more importantly understand the differences between an [**In-Memory Table**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/in-memory-oltp-in-memory-optimization?view=sql-server-ver15) vs a regular **Table**, specifically with regards to locks and retry logic for **In-Memory Tables** being different, which may be important to consider and cause you to make additional changes to your application.

Additional resources for **In-Memory Tables**:

1. [Microsoft Docs - Memory Optimized Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/introduction-to-memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. [Microsoft Docs - Transactions with Memory Optimized Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/transactions-with-memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: thanks - the 2nd link is really useful, biggest risks seem to be associated with row updates & we don't intend to do any of those but there may be some edge cases we need to code for.